# NotificationListener in websphere 8.5.5

Tags: websphere

Does attached notification listener vanishes on JVM stop/restart ? Is their any way we could persist that listener meaning if JVM stops/restarts then same listener still exists ?

Comment: This question is kind of vague. What kind of notification listener are you asking about?

Comment: listener for events generated by websphere like TYPE_THREAD_MONITOR_THREAD_HUNG

Comment: Do you mean that the same listener should exist after the stop process is complete and the restart process has begun?

Comment: Are you talking about JMX notifications?